# Add variable inside an array in PHP

Tags: php

Let's assume we have a PHP variable like this.

```
$codes = 29017,28966,28965,28963,28958,28881,28880,28878,28877,28876;
```

I want to add this inside of this. Cant use **echo** either. It gives an error.

```
$rqData->hotels = [ "hotel" => [  $codes ] ];
```

This above method is not correct. So I need a proper way to get an output like this

```
$rqData->hotels = [ "hotel" => [  29017,28966,28965,28963,28958,28881,28880,28878,28877,28876 ] ];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$codes` is a string or an array? *It's invalid* the way you have posted it.

Comment: I want it without double-quotes. Just as it is.

Comment: _"I want it without double-quotes"_ - If it should be a string, then you need to add quotes (single or double quotes doesn't matter). If you want it as an array, you need to create it as one.

Comment: Agree with above. The first line is wrong.  If you want it as an array just surround it with [ ] but if a string surround it with double-quotes. If you have to have it as a string but want it as an array thereafter you can explode the comma separated values later with $codes = explode(",",$codes);

Comment: As you've noticed, we don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. Please edit your question to include a _proper_ and _detailed_ explanation of what you want. Your current question and examples are very unclear (especially since you're defining `$codes` in a way that would throw syntax errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codes has to be in either double-quotes as a comma separate list or as an array by surrounding the integer list with square brackets [1,2,3,4,5,6];

Below makes the string an array when you assign it.

```
$codes = "29017,28966,28965,28963,28958,28881,28880,28878,28877,28876";
$rqData->hotels["hotel"] = explode(",",$codes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$codes = [29017,28966,28965,28963,28958,28881,28880,28878,28877,28876];

$rqData->hotels[ "hotel" ] = $codes;

print_r($rqData);
```

This prints the following output:

```
stdClass Object (
[hotels] => Array
    (
        [hotel] => Array
            (
                [0] => 29017
                [1] => 28966
                [2] => 28965
                [3] => 28963
                [4] => 28958
                [5] => 28881
                [6] => 28880
                [7] => 28878
                [8] => 28877
                [9] => 28876
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: No this gives an error. Missing [ ] is the problem.

Comment: If you want to make an array out of `$codes`, you have to use [] around it. See how arrays are created here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @ShalinNipuna - _"No this gives an error. Missing [ ] is the problem"_ You need to expand on that. Where do you get an error and what exactly does it say?  There's nothing in the code in this answer that would throw an error. You need to give us the complete picture or we won't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$codes = "29017,28966,28965";

    $rqData->hotels[ "hotel" ] = [$codes];

    echo "<pre>";
     print_r($rqData);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  stdClass Object
(
    [hotels] => Array
        (
            [hotel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 29017,28966,28965
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add the hotel key to the $rqData->hotels dataset and then wrap your codes into an array syntax.

Try this:

```
$rqData->hotels['hotels'] = [$codes];
```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP is currently doing: `$rqData->hotels = [ "hotel" => [  $codes ] ];`?